# New python venv is using global packages

Tags: python, package, python-venv, requirements.txt

So far I wasn't aware that I should be creating a new venv for each project and so, I installed every package I needed globally.
Now when I want to start using python -m venv env, my program runs fine, even though I have installed no packages at all.
I assume it uses global packages, because when I do `pip freeze` I get no packages listed.

I'm trying to create a `requirements.txt` file that'll list only the packages I need for this project, but it's empty, and my code runs fine!
The `include-system-site-packages = false` is also set in the `pyvenv.cfg` file, I really don't get this.

Comment: How are you running the application? It could be the case that you're running it with the system python interpreter, in which case the virtual environment wouldn't be used.

Comment: I'm running it in the VS Code, I selected the env Python interpreter. `which python` and `which pip` give me the correct ones

Comment: And there's no `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top of the file? Could you try running it from the command line?

Comment: I'm not sure how to run it from command line and, at the top of which file should that be? I'm on Windows 10, using bash in VS code

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Apparently my app was using a global Flask package, which had access to other global packages.
I uninstalled global Flask package, which forced my app to use the env Flask, along with other env packages.

Now `requirements.txt` gets rendered properly.